# How to program DirectX without Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, directx, sublimetext2

so this is pretty much what I wanna do... I recently start using sublime text 2 as my new number 1 editor.
I also want to start programming directX and I was wondering if there is way to use sublime text2 instead of Visual Studio.

I was thinking of something like...

...programming in Sublime Text2
...compiling/building within Sublime Text2
...debugging from Visual Studio? or maybe WinDbg? never used it

I know that I could just have a normal VisalStudio project setup and just writing the code with ST2 but then it I will have problems when I want to add new files in sublime text etc.. I always have to keep the visual studio filter and project file up to date...

I need some kind of workflow which make sense :) I am also wondering if there are not more people out there which don't like Visual Studio that much or have limited resources on their machines like me. It can not be that all DirectX Programmers are using Visual Studio?

Comment: Your question is a bit odd. How is the DirectX bit relevant? It's just an API, you can use it from any C++ compiler you want. And other languages as well. Can we conclude you are just looking for a good C++ command line compiler?

Comment: You can compile files written in any editor using the command line compiler provided with visual studio, using the CL command. You don't have to set up visual studio projects if you don't want to. But it's not clear to me what you are asking..

Comment: well, at first I don't know how to setup the CL compiler provided with visual studio.
I mentioned DirectX as an example for an external SDK which I am using and I would setup all external included dirs / libraries etc within visual studio, and also for the reason that it will use the WINAPI which I could believe is something which should be considered when not using VS.
My problem is that I cannot find any resources which might help me to setup such "workflow"

Answer (score 3):

You can attach to a running process with Visual Studio or WinDBG.  You can also open any .EXE as a project in Visual Studio or in WinDBG to allow you to start the process under the debugger.  So that part of your work flow shouldn't be an issue.

That said the part of your workflow that appears difficult is the compiling/building part.  After reviewing Sublime Text 2's documentation for build systems http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html it does not appear that is really trying to provide support for the complexity of compiling multiple C++ source files into object files and then linking those together with the necessary libs.  It does seem feasible to create a ST2 build system that will compile and link one C++ source file in to an EXE, but that may not be sufficient for your needs.

https://github.com/tillig/SublimeMSBuild may be your best bet as it both provides support for editing msbuild files in ST2 and and actually building them.  That said it does not appear that will automatically generate or update msbuild project files from C++ files in ST2 so you would still have to keep the msbuild project file up-to-date, but the task could be done in ST2 rather than in VS.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me alot. I now can build my directX Projects within ST2. For now I need to setup a VS project with all included/libs etc and then I can compile in ST2. Since this MSBuild Package comes with an MSbuild script snipped I figured that I also could write my own without opening VS and setting up the project. I am also wondering where exactly I can find those build script in my VS project folder?I actually though all those informations are stored in the VC++ Project file.

Comment: Unfortunately there is not much information about the MSBuild Package. I also have no idea how to build a Release version..

Comment: The VC++ Project files are MSBuild files (scripts).  MSBuild files use an XML format.  You'll need to use ST2 to open the .vcxproj directly in ST2 so you can edit it there.

Comment: ah ok and  how do I tell the MSCompiler when I want to have a release version?

Comment: The MCCompiler / cl.exe  has no concept of Debug vs Release Configurations (versions).  While there are some compiler flags that are typically only used with one configuration or the other it isn't something the compiler enforces or infers.  Take a look a VC++ project generated by VS and you'll see it has both Debug and Release configurations.  MSBuild is aware of configurations though, and the /p:Configuration=Release command line switch will tell it to build the Release configuration.

Comment: Thanks you really helped me. /p:Configuration=Release  works perfect.
Now I just need to find out how to setup a run variant in the MSBuild.sublime-build file.

Answer (score 0):

The question was asked this a long time ago, but maybe this answer will help someone, here's what I do:

In this scenario it is best to leave Visual Studio closed completely. You can just use a makefile to build your project. You can run the makefile and executable from Sublime Text directly.

- set `Project >> Add Folder to Project`
- `Tools >> Build System >> Make`
- install MinGW if you haven't already
- create a file called just 'makefile' in the folder, it can look something like this:

> ```
> main.exe: main.o
>   g++ -o main.exe *.o -lkernel32 -luser32
>   main.exe
> main.o: main.cpp
>   g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o
> ```

(Note: this only links kernel32 and user32, for DirectX you need some more stuff, if you dont know what then copy them from VisualStudio.)

- press ctrl-B

This makefile also automatically runs the executable. You could also replace the line `main.exe` with `gdb main.exe` to use the debugger that is available on most systems (on windows you would have to install it).

Comment: I am as much a Make and GNU C fan as the other guy, but do you have a suggestion on how to link against DirectX and leverage it with the GNU compiler? Because the above only gives you basic WinAPI, if I remember correctly (judging from linking to `kernel32` and `user32` stubs)